# Java Lottery Game - Iterating through arrays

Tags: java

Im creating a lottery game where the program checks if the user guessed any sequences correct.A sequence must include two or more numbers and must not have gaps.For example :
23 56 67 **06 43 22** 59 24 90 66 and user entered: 01 **06 43 22** 89.
The lottery game generated 10 random numbers from 1 - 100 and user was allowed to input 5 numbers.I'm new to java so I have tried for loops (seems like best solution) but it doesn't work.How do I check if the user guessed 1 - 5 sequences and then prints a message , for example "You guessed 2 sequences".Here is my code.

```
     // to check if user guessed a sequence
        
    int input,lottoNums;
        for ( int i = 1;i < numbers.length; ++i) {
            input = numbers[i];
            for (int j = 1; j < lottery.length; ++j) {
                lottoNums = lottery[j];
                
                if (input == lottoNums) {
                    System.out.println("You guessed two sequences correct.");
                }
                for ( i = 2; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                    input = numbers[i];
                    j = 2;
                    
                    if ( input == lottoNums) {
                        System.out.println("You guessed 3 sequences correct.");
                    }
                }
                
                for ( i = 3; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                    input = numbers[i];
                    j = 3;
                    
                    if ( input == lottoNums) {
                        System.out.println("You guessed 4 sequences correct.");
                    }
                }
                for ( i = 4; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                    input = numbers[i];
                    j = 4;
                    
                    if ( input == lottoNums) {
                        System.out.println("You guessed 5 sequences correct.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Drop the array/for loop idea and look at java container types such as set, queue and map. Set and map can give you boolean answers if you query them for containing element X. Let them do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an algorithm. Search for "find longest common string" or something along those lines, there should be quite a few example implementations using dynamic programming.

[Here is an example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-substring-dp-29/)

Comment: is there any way I can solve this problem with arrays?

Comment: The link I pasted uses arrays

Answer (score 0):

You  can store the values in ArrayList Or any other Collection in java. And for checking the input of user you can use  .contains(num) method.

Comment: can you please show me an example I keep trying every method and can't seem to get it right